# Odoo Is it possible to stop adding the project's followers to its task when it is created?

Tags: odoo, task, project, odoo-9, nofollow

I have been managing Odoo 9 and there are some complain from customers who use odoo project to create issues about getting a lot of emails when tasks is created and commenting in the task.

When I remove the followers from the project, then the followers is not able to see the project anymore. That's not what I want.

So I tried to find a function that add its project followers to its task when created to override and thus remove the followers to its task created.

But somehow I cannot find the function to override.

Is there any other suggestion for me to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it  using alternative solution, system will add followers in the task but system will not send any emails.

```
class project_task(models.Model)

    _inherit="project.task"

    @api.model
    def create(self,vals)
        context=dict(self._context or {})
        context.update({'mail_notrack:True'})    
        return super(project_task,self.with_context(context)).create(vals)

    @api.multi 
    def write(self,vals):
        context=dict(self._context or {})
        context.update({'mail_notrack:True'}) 
    return super(project_task,self.with_context(context)).write(vals)
```

> `**mail_notrack**`` : at create and write, do not perform the value
>   tracking
>       creating messages
>
> In context you can pass **mail_notrack True**, then system will not
>   send any email to ERP users when task is create or change stages.

This may help you.

Comment: thanks! this is not what I wanted but might use this solution for later. thanks